# Health effects of wearing ear plugs at night, ear phones during the day

Tags: ear, earplugs-earphones

I've just realised I wear ear plugs whilst im asleep (~8 hours) and then go to work and wear ear phones all day (~8->12 hours) which means there are only about 4->8 hours a day I don't have something in my ear.

What are the health effects of this? Particularly ear heatlh...

Comment: If there is music playing in those plugs all the time, you can probably expect tinnitus and progressive hearing loss as you get older. I've never been able to figure out where people find enough music in the world to listen 24/7 and not get tired of it. Do you ever wonder what the world sounds like?

Answer (score 1):

**In a nutshell:**

- **mechanical effects** - earwax impaction in the auditory canal, external otitis
- **noise exposure** (i.e. songs) - some degree of hearing loss.

These are the possible consequences. It doesn't mean you are sure to have them.